# Firebase Authentication Service

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I want to set multiple authentication services. As if user either sign in with email and password or phone number, but I want user to signUp with both email and password and phone number.

Answer (score 0):

In Firebase Authentication terms this means that you want the user to sign up with multiple authentication provider. This is possible, although you'll have to implement the flow for it in your own application code. You then can [link the providers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/account-linking) together through the Firebase Authentication API, so that the user ends up with a single ID.